# Statistical test for positive and negative predictive value

Tags: epidemiology, contingency-tables, p-value

I was reading through a paper and I saw a table with a comparison between PPV (Positive Predictive Value) and NPV (Negative Predictive Value). They did some kind of statistical test for them, this is a sketch of the table:

```
PPV    NPV    p-value
65.9   100    < 0.00001
...
```

Every rows refers to a particular contingency table.

What kind of hypothesis test did they do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming a cross-classification like the one shown below (here, for a screening instrument)

[image]

we can define four measures of screening accuracy and predictive power:

- *Sensitivity* (se), a/(a + c), i.e. the probability of the screen providing a positive result given that disease is present;
- *Specificity* (sp), d/(b + d), i.e. the probability of the screen providing a negative result given that disease is absent;
- *Positive predictive value* (PPV), a/(a+b), i.e. the probability of patients with positive test results who are correctly diagnosed (as positive);
- *Negative predictive value* (NPV), d/(c+d), i.e. the probability of patients with negative test results who are correctly diagnosed (as negative).

Each four measures are simple proportions computed from the observed data. A suitable statistical test would thus be a [binomial (exact) test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test), which should be available in most statistical packages, or many online calculators. The tested hypothesis is whether the observed proportions significantly differ from 0.5 or not. I found, however, more interesting to provide confidence intervals rather than a single significance test, since it gives an information about the precision of measurement. Anyway, for reproducing the results you shown, you need to know the total margins of your two-way table (you only gave the PPV and NPV as %).

As an example, suppose that we observe the following data (the CAGE questionnaire is a screening questionnaire for alcohol):

[image]

then in R the PPV would be computed as follows:

```
> binom.test(99, 142)

    Exact binomial test

data:  99 and 142 
number of successes = 99, number of trials = 142, p-value = 2.958e-06
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5 
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.6145213 0.7714116 
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.6971831
```

If you are using SAS, then you can look at the Usage Note 24170: [How can I estimate sensitivity, specificity, positive and negative predictive values, false positive and negative probabilities, and the likelihood ratios?](http://support.sas.com/kb/24/170.html).

To compute confidence intervals, the gaussian approximation, $p \pm 1.96 \times \sqrt{p(1-p)/n}$ (1.96 being the quantile of the standard normal distribution at $p=0.975$ or $1-\alpha/2$ with $\alpha=5$%), is used in practice, especially when the proportions are quite small or large (which is often the case here).

For further reference, you can look at

> Newcombe, RG. [Two-Sided Confidence
>   Intervals for the Single Proportion:
>   Comparison of Seven Methods](http://www.stats.org.uk/statistical-inference/Newcombe1998.pdf).
>   *Statistics in Medicine*, 17, 857-872 (1998).

Comment: Thanks. Ok, I read in very beginning of the paper that they used Chi-square test for all categorical variables. The classification table written doesn't refer to a variable in particular, it is the output of a classification task. It isn't very clear! Now I suppose they did a classical test on proportion.. maybe Chi-square..

Comment: I had a look to this question again and I have seen that p-value doesn't refer neither PPV nor NPV, it refers to the entire row. I think the test they had should be associated to the whole contingency-table.

Comment: @Simone So, if I understand you correctly, you suggest that the authors provide PPV and NPV values but gave the p-value corresponding to a global association test of the 2x2 table? Is it related to this recent question, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9464/can-someone-give-me-details-about-a-particular-confidence-interval-formula?

Comment: Yes, it would be related to that question if p-value were associated either to PPV or to NPV. And in that case you gave the solution. The test corresponds to the whole 2x2 table, I won't ever know what kind of test it is!

Answer (score 2):

Please see

Kosinski, Andrzej S. A weighted generalized score statistic for comparison of predictive values of diagnostic tests. Statistics in Medicine http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/sim.5587
published online: 22 AUG 2012