# How do you compute confidence intervals for positive predictive value?

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, contingency-tables

How do you compute confidence intervals for positive predictive value?

The standard error is:

$$SE = \sqrt{ \frac{PPV(1-PPV)}{TP+FP}} $$

Is that right? (here my concern is the denominator)

Does that formula work for any similar ratio in a 2x2 table. E.g. for sensitivity, it would be

$$SE = \sqrt{ \frac{SENS(1-SENS)}{FP+TN}} $$

Is that right? (here my concern is that it is generalizable to other ratios as long as you get the denominator right)

And the for the 95% confidence intervals:

$$CI_{PPV} = PPV \pm 1.96*SE$$

Is that right? (my concern here is how to go from SE to the confidence interval)

(of course with all the cell restrictions like $n\cdot p\cdot (1-p) \ge 5$)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

Comment: Thanks for the link. My question is if I am getting $n$, the denominator, right for the different variations (and confirmation that the other instances are right).

Comment: This related question might be useful, [Statistical test for Positive and Negative Predictive Value](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6309/statistical-test-for-positive-and-negative-predictive-value).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your first SE formula is correct. The second SE formula which concerns sensitivity should have the total number of positive cases in the denominator:
  $$SE_\text{sensitivity} = \sqrt{ \frac{SENS(1-SENS)}{TP+FN}} $$

The logic is that sensitivity = $\frac{TP}{TP+FN}$, and the denominator in the SE formula is the same.

As @onestop pointed out in their comment [methods of calculating a binomial proportion confidence interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) can be used here. The method you follow is the normal approximation, however unless you have really large counts other methods like the Wilson interval will be more accurate.

Comment: Argh...yes...I mixed up sensitivity and specificity.